# Sparse signal recovery (nonlinear case)

Tags: convexity, nonlinear-optimization, combinatorial-optimization, compressed-sensing, regularization

Let $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, it may be that $K$ is "very thin" (e.g. $K$ is a $k$-dimensional affine subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, with $k \ll n$). I'm interested in the case where $K$ is nonconvex, but for theoretical elegance, one can begin with the case where $K$ is indeed convex. Let $s \ll n$ (the "sparsity"). Consider the **sparse signal recovery problem**:
$$\tag{1} \label{e:genprob} \text{Find } x^* \in K \text{ such that }\|x^*\|_0 \leq s,$$
where $\|\cdot\|_0$ counts the number of nonzero entries.

**My question:** Although \eqref{e:genprob} is NP-hard in general, in some cases (almost any affine $K$, using LASSO/compressed sensing/convex optimization/$\ell^1$ regularization) one can solve \eqref{e:genprob} in polynomial time. As far as I can tell, these efficient algorithms do not work when $K$ is a general convex set (or worse, a fully general set!) Can anyone point me to some literature/algorithms for solving \eqref{e:genprob}, e.g. when $K$ is convex, with the same or similar astonishing efficiency of the LASSO/compressed sensing? Are there any books or papers on this? Is there a theory for it? Is it an open problem? Aside from the convex optimization/compressed sensing/LASSO literature, I also looked in "random sampling" (linear algebra) because I use that, but didn't find it there either.

### Mathematical discussion

This is related to sparse signal recovery, in the following way. Assume that $f(x)$ is some function, and consider the problem:
$$\label{e:optprob} \alpha^* = \tag{2} \inf_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} f(x).$$
One assumes there is some $x^*$ with $\|x^*\|_0 = s$, such that $f(x^*)$ is minimal. Then, problem \eqref{e:optprob} can be converted to problem \eqref{e:genprob} by setting
$$\tag{3} \label{e:Kset} K = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \; : \; f(x) = \alpha^* \}.$$
Consider the following relaxation of \eqref{e:genprob}, \eqref{e:Kset}
$$\tag{4} \label{e:lasso} \inf_{z \in \mathbb{R}^n \; : \; \|z\|_1 \leq t} f(z).$$
When $f(x) = \|b-Ax\|_2$ then $K$ is an affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and \eqref{e:lasso} is called the LASSO method. It is well-known that, for almost every $b,A$ that have a sparse solution $x^*$ of \eqref{e:genprob}, then $z^*=x^*$ when $t = \|x^*\|_1$. However, this quickly breaks down in the nonlinear case. For example, let $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a closed convex set that contains an $s$-sparse point $x^*$ and $0 \notin K$, and define $f(x) = d(x,K)$ the Euclidian distance between $x$ and $K$. For almost any such $K$, \eqref{e:lasso} fails to recover a sparse solution of \eqref{e:genprob} for any $t\geq 0$.

I have been working on an alternate convex relaxation of \eqref{e:genprob}, and I believe that my relaxation recovers the solution of \eqref{e:genprob} with high probability even if $K$ is nonaffine. Because my relaxation is convex, it admits highly efficient solvers. I tried to find references on this, since it seems like a very canonical problem, and I have failed, to my surprise.

Comment: Have you had a look at Projection On Convex Sets and / or Subgradient methods? This would answer the convex case I believe.

Comment: I'm aware of POCS and Subgradient methods in general, but I'm not sure how these are directly applicable to my problem. Could you clarify for me? Intuitively, I would want to use POCS to alternatively project onto K and onto a set S of sparse vectors, but even if K is convex, S is not convex. So hopefully I misunderstood you, and there's something I'm not seeing?